# Parse Server S3 file adapter not working

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-s3, parse-server

I have been trying to set up S3 File Adapter with no luck. I am starting Parse Server using[PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) and this is my ecosystem.json file:

```
 "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "parse-wrapper",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-server",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse",
    "env": {
      "PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD_CODE_MAIN": "/home/parse/cloud/main.js",
      "PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI": "myuri",
      "PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID": "myappid",
      "PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": "my master key",
      "PARSE_SERVER_JAVASCRIPT_KEY": "myjskey",
      "PARSE_SERVER_FILES_ADAPTER": "parse-server-s3-adapter",
      "S3_ACCESS_KEY": "MYS3ACCESSKEY",
      "S3_SECRET_KEY": "MYS3SECRETKEY",
      "S3_BUCKET": "thenameofmybucket"
    }
  }]
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is one year ago, I wish the solution could help others because i had also spent times to research about pm2 setup.

```
"env": {
    "PARSE_SERVER_FILES_ADAPTER": {
      "module": "parse-server-s3-adapter",
      "options": {
        "accessKey": "MYS3ACCESSKEY",
        "secretKey": "MYS3SECRETKEY",
        "bucket": "thenameofmybucket",
        "region": "ap-southeast-1",
        "bucketPrefix": "",
        "directAccess": true,
        "baseUrl": null,
        "baseUrlDirect": false,
        "signatureVersion": "v4",
        "globalCacheControl": null,
        "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256|aws:kms"
      }
}
```

you might revise the value of `accessKey`, `secretKey`, `bucket` and `region`